# Is the iOS 7 table view swipe feasible for critical features?

Tags: interaction-design, ios, menu, gestures, swipe

Is it a good idea to embed critical features of a table view only in the menu only visible and accessable by swiping the table view element?
In this case it would be delete and modify the selected element, which are for my understanding quite fitting features for the menu. But the whole functionality isn't the most intuitive if you are not aware of it in the first palce.

The other option would be to either add redundant buttons, always visible without interaction or leave out the swipe functionality completely.

Any help, opinions and experiences appreciated!

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the table swipe actions are more like "power user" shortcuts. In the example of Mail, the Delete action and all the actions under the More action are available from the action bar of the message detail view if the user taps the row itself.

Given that direction, I'd suggest not using the table swipe actions as primary actions, but instead as shortcuts for power users.

Comment: Agreed. And many 3rd-party apps do not provide this interaction pattern in their list views, making users even less likely to expect it even if it's an OS-level standard.